# Can i change java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock into java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

Tags: java, locking, reentrantreadwritelock

I have a method which creates the lock.

```
ReadWriteLock  lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
```

Then I pass this object into a method using Lock Interface.

```
method(Lock lock)
```

inside the method I just do the following.

```
final ReentrantReadWriteLock currentLock = (ReentrantReadWriteLock) lock;
```

Comment: Just take a look into javadoc of ReadWriterLock / ReentrantReadWriteLock, and see which interface is implemented by it.  This is something you can answer yourself, that ReadWriteLock is not a Lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ReentrantReadWriteLock is not a Lock. It contains two related Locks a read lock and a write lock. You can pass either of these but you can't get the original ReentrantReadWriteLock back.